# Combine smallcaps in frame title, math upright + greek text

Tags: beamer, fonts, unicode-math, greek

I am desperately trying to get three things working in Beamer:

1. Have the frame title displayed in smallcaps.
2. Have math formulas displayed upright.
3. Print greek text with diacritics.

The first two points work splendidly with the MWE below, but greek text won't work. I have tried adding

```
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\greekfontsf}{CMU Sans Serif}
```

to the .tex file. This way, I had greek text, but the frame title did not show up in small caps anymore. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%%% Mathe-Font gerade %%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
%%% Griechisch %%%

\usepackage{exscale} % große Formeln sehen schöner aus
%%% Folientitel weiter unten, zentriert und in Kapitälchen %%%
\usepackage{textcase,regexpatch}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \makeatletter
  \regexpatchcmd{\insertframetitle}
    {(\c{usebeamertemplate}.*)\c{fi}}
    {\c{NoCaseChange}\cB\{\1\cE\}\c{fi}}
    {}{}%
  \makeatother
  \vspace{1ex} \huge\centerline{\scshape{\insertframetitle}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The frame title is in caps -- as desired.}
Here, the text is normal, as expected.
Also, math formulas are displayed the way I would like them to be, i.\,e., upright:
$\{ \langle x,y \rangle \mid x \in a \land y \in b \} := \{ z \in \mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{P}(a\cup b)) \mid \exists x \exists y (x\in a \land y \in b \land z=\{ \{ x \}, \{ x,y \} \}) \}$
Problematically, though, greek letters are not displayed at all: Ἀριστοτέλης ὁ φιλόσοφος ἐστιν.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Being a bloody beginner with LaTeX, I am grateful for any other suggestion on cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print Greek letters, you need to load a font that supports Greek. So, loading CMU Sans Serif and CMU Serif is a good idea. Since both fonts seem to support Greek, you don't need to define a font specifically for Greek text. Note that you cannot use `fontspec` together with PDFLaTeX but you need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX then.

You also need to specify that you want the frame title to be printed in CMU Serif, because CMU Sans Serif has no small caps. You can do so by inserting `\rmfamily` in your redefintion of the `frametitle`.

Putting everything together:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%%% Mathe-Font gerade %%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
%%% Griechisch %%%

\usepackage{exscale} % große Formeln sehen schöner aus
%%% Folientitel weiter unten, zentriert und in Kapitälchen %%%
\usepackage{textcase,regexpatch}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \makeatletter
  \regexpatchcmd{\insertframetitle}
    {(\c{usebeamertemplate}.*)\c{fi}}
    {\c{NoCaseChange}\cB\{\1\cE\}\c{fi}}
    {}{}%
  \makeatother
  \vspace{1ex} \huge\centerline{\rmfamily\scshape{\insertframetitle}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The frame title is in caps -- as desired.}
Here, the text is normal, as expected.
Also, math formulas are displayed the way I would like them to be, i.\,e., upright:
$\{ \langle x,y \rangle \mid x \in a \land y \in b \} := \{ z \in \mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{P}(a\cup b)) \mid \exists x \exists y (x\in a \land y \in b \land z=\{ \{ x \}, \{ x,y \} \}) \}$
Problematically, though, greek letters are not displayed at all: Ἀριστοτέλης ὁ φιλόσοφος ἐστιν.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output should then be:

[image]

---

Off topic: You can probably replace

```
\usepackage{textcase,regexpatch}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \makeatletter
  \regexpatchcmd{\insertframetitle}
    {(\c{usebeamertemplate}.*)\c{fi}}
    {\c{NoCaseChange}\cB\{\1\cE\}\c{fi}}
    {}{}%
  \makeatother
  \vspace{1ex} \huge\centerline{\scshape{\insertframetitle}}
}
```

by just

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vspace{1ex} \huge\centerline{\scshape{\insertframetitle}}
}
```